# How to do routing for multi language url in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, middleware

I would like to know how to do routing got multi language url in nodejs,

I have following routes, currently, each language generating route in that language as shown below,
Since have more than 5 languages, how to do efficiently.

```
app.js

app.use('/:lang/detail/:service', serviceRouter);
app.use('/:lang/xhixhi/:service', serviceRouter);
app.use('/:lang/servise/:service', serviceRouter);

app.use('/:lang/about', aboutRouter);
app.use('/:lang/guan-yu-wo-men', aboutRouter);
app.use('/:lang/tentang-kami', serviceRouter);

app.use('/:lang/contact', contactRouter);
app.use('/:lang/lian-xi-wo-men', contactRouter);
app.use('/:lang/kontak', contactRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make as much of it as possible table driven rather than repeating code.

```
const routeInfo = [
   {url: "/:lang/{tag}/:service", words: ["detail", "xhixhi", "servise"], router: serviceRouter}, 
   {url: "/:lang/{tag}", words: ["about", "guan-yu-wo-men", "tentang-kami"], router: aboutRouter}, 
   {url: "/:lang/{tag}", words: ["contact", "lian-xi-wo-men", "kontak"], router: contactRouter}, 
];
```

Then, loop through the table to build all the routes:

```
for (let info of routeInfo) {
    for (let word of info.words) {
       let url = info.url.replace("{tag}", word);
       app.use(url, info.router);
    }
}
```

Adding a language would just involve adding another entry to each word array.

Comment: thanks, I have a route with regex, have tried above approach for it , not working only for regex, can please help.app.use(/^\/(en|zh-hans)\/((money|hui-kuan-cong|paisa)-(.+)-(to|zhi|kho)-(.+))/, pageRouter);

Comment: @miyavv - You'd have to show exactly what problem you're trying to solve with the regex route as it looks like something different than you have in your question.  I'd suggest a new question for that since your original question didn't have anything to do with a regex.